# defparam inside generate block in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In design, the top level module A has two instantiation of another module B

```
module A (....);
B (.C(C1)...) inst1;
B (.C(C2)...) inst2;
```

The module B has some parameter which I would like to assign from the testbench using generate block.

```
//Testbench
module test_top ();
A (....) A1;
generate 
for (genvar k = 0; k<2; k++) begin
    defparam A1.instk.C = 0;
end
endgenerate
```

The compilation on NCSIM is causing error on defparam statement. where by it is unable to get the path of the instance. May be it is because of the generate statement.
Is it legal to use defparam inside genertate block ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `defparam` - it is deprecated. Instead, set parameters using the `#( ... )` syntax.

Secondly, your instances of module `B` need to be in a generate loop if you wish to refer to them using a `genvar`.

Finally, if you did want to use *hierarchical naming* with `generate` then you have to name the block inside the `generate` statement. The `$display` in the `initial` block gives an example - the hierarchical name of `I` inside module instance `A1`.

For example:

```
module A #(integer WIDTH) (input [WIDTH-1:0] I, output [WIDTH-1:0] O);

  generate 
    for (genvar k = 0; k<WIDTH; k++) begin : BLOCK_NAME
      B #(.WIDTH(WIDTH),.BIT(k)) Binst (.I(I), .O(O[k]));
    end
  endgenerate 

endmodule

module B #(integer WIDTH, BIT) (input [WIDTH-1:0] I, output O);

  assign O = I[BIT];

endmodule

module test_top;

  reg [1:0]  I;
  wire [1:0] O;

  A #(.WIDTH(2)) A1 (.I(I), .O(O));

  initial
    $display("I[1]= %b", test_top.A1.BLOCK_NAME[1].Binst.I);

endmodule
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4PyL

Comment: how to provide different value of parameter "BIT" for Binst inside test_top module, where "module A" is not defined inside module "test_top" ?

Comment: @Sourabh Well, I guess you'd have to use `defparam`, then, but it would be better to refactor your code so that it wasn't necessary. My example shows how the hierarchical naming works with `generate` statements.

Comment: Minor correction: `defparam` is not deprecated _yet_, but it is _scheduled_ for deprecation. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) § C.4.1 _Defparam statements_ : "The practice of using `defparam` statements is highly discouraged.Engineers are encouraged to take advantage of the explicit inline parameter redefinition capability."